# When does "second annihilator" of a (principal) ideal equal the ideal itself , ie $Ann_R(Ann_R(r))=Rr$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a (local) ring and $r\in R$. When do the equations  $Ann_R(Ann_R(r))=Rr$ or $\sqrt{Ann_R(Ann_R(r))}=\sqrt{Rr}$ hold?
I already know that it holds for Artinian Gorenstein rings (due to an exercise in Bruns-Herzog) and it seems to be true for $R=\Bbb {Z}/n\Bbb {Z}$.
The question is more interesting when  we also assume that $Ann_R(r)\in Ass(R)$

Comment: Quasi-Frobenius Rings are precisely the (Artinian) rings that Ann(ann(I))=I, ann(Ann(T))=T , Ann= right annihilator, ann=left annihilator.

Comment: $R=\Bbb {Z}/n\Bbb {Z}$ is itself an artinian Gorenstein ring.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384374/when-does-second-annihilator-of-a-principal-ideal-equal-the-ideal-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, it suffices for $(r)$ to be an interesection of minimal primes; in fact, more generally if $J$ is any intersection of minimal primes then $J=Annih(Annih(J))$.  (This requires only that $R$ be commutative and noetherian; you don't need local.)

This is Lemma 2.17 in an old paper of mine called "Patching Modules of Finite Projective Dimension", where the stated hypothesis is "Let $R$ be any (commutative) ring", but it now seems to me that the proof requires $R$ to be noetherian.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. But I'm curious about the  conditions on $r\in R$ that  implies the equations. Don't you think that $Ann_R(r)\in Ass(R)$ can help somehow?

Comment: Is there some analog of this for non-Noetherian rings?

Answer (score 4):

Let $l(X)$ denote a left annihilator, and $r(X)$ denote a right annihilator.

A ring is called *right P-injective* if $l(r(a))=Ra$ for all $a\in R$. You can find this condition discussed in detail in Nicholson and Yousif's [*Quasi-Frobenius rings*](http://books.google.com/books?id=yHke_PLh8gsC&pg=PA96&dq=P+injective+ring&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z2CKUef2Hsq9yQGWhoBw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=P%20injective%20ring&f=false) on page 96.

Rings which are right self-injective are right $P$-injective (and so that's why $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has the property for every $n>1$.)

Also, all von Neumann regular rings are left and right $P$ injective, and these can be noncommutative, nonNoetherian and non-self-injective.

Answer (score 4):

Long time ago, I proved, but never published, that if $R$ is generically Gorenstein, meaning that all $R_P$ are Gorenstein with $P$ an associated (necessarily) minimal prime, then $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(I))=I$, for any ideal $I$ with non-zero annihilator.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to access the details of the proof?